# Mysterious missing transactional replication tokens

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication, availability-groups

I am looking at implementing Transactional Replication subscriptions in an AlwaysOn AvailabilityGroup. I tried to use this as a guide:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/backup-and-recovery/expanding-alwayson-availability-groups-with-replication-subscribers/

The reason I say tried is not in anyway besmirching the author - in this case he is dealing w/ push subscriptions and we are doing pull. There was a spectacular flame out trying to Initialize from LSN (The transactions required for synchronizing the subscription with the specified log sequence number (LSN) are unavailable at the Distributor. Specify a higher LSN.
) (perhaps b/c this is a pull subscription and it moved on, whereas in the example the push agent was disabled and then brought up on the now Primary?). Following this I just 're-initialized' the subscription (it is not that big a publication).

Anyhow, now Replication Monitor, which from experience can be an unreliable narrator up there with the greats of literature, tells me this subscription's performance is 'Excellent' and that it was last synchronized 1 minute ago as of this writing, yet when I try to insert Tracer Tokens to get a feel for latency this subscription is nowhere to be seen. In other areas of Replication monitor or checking out the SQL Server Agent jobs there are no big oddities.

What is going on? Is using pull as opposed to push subscriptions not advised in this scenario? I am somewhat befuddled at the moment and any enlightenment would be welcomed and appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This type of behavior is usually caused by an uninitialized subscription. Make sure the snapshot agent ran successfully and the distribution agent is running too.

Check out level 10 of my [Stairway to SQL Server Replication](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72401/) for more help on troubleshooting replication.

Comment: Interesting. I forced a re-initialization, but well after that it continued to be AWOL. But I should look deeper. I wiped the thing and will take a look at your link. I haven't really formalized my method for digging info out of system tables but clearly I should...